# How can I set the SelectedIndex in a ComboBox having element binding?

Tags: data-binding, mvvm, combobox, silverlight-4.0, selectedindex

I have two ComboBoxes, one for Organisation and one for Region. When selecting Organisation I want the Region combobox to update itself with the related regions. After selecting Organisation and Region I can type in a Site to a textbox and store it to db (ADD mode). I've completed that with this code:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbOrganisation"
      Grid.Row="0"
      Grid.Column="1" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding OrganisationEntries}"
      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedOrganisation, Mode=TwoWay}"
      SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedOrganisationIndex}"
      DisplayMemberPath="Description">
</ComboBox>

<ComboBox x:Name="cbRegions"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Grid.Column="1" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=cbOrganisation, Path=SelectedItem.Regions}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRegion, Mode=TwoWay}"
    SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedRegionIndex}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Description" >
</ComboBox>
```

So, I'm using element to element binding, with the second combobox having the first one as ItemSource.

Now, I've got a new problem when I want to EDIT a site in my collection. In EDIT mode, I want the two dropdowns to be preselected and disabled (BusinessRule is that I can edit the sitename, not which organisation og region it's connected to). So by setting the SelectedIndex property on Organisation combobox I get my organisation selected, but when doing the same on the Regions combobox it fails with an Object Reference error.
Any clue what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need to check a bit deeper in to your code. I did up the quick sample below, and it works fine setting the `SelectedIndex` even when the combos are disabled. If you try and set an index that is too high or low then you get an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, not a null reference.

Maybe you are using a Linq query to find an item in the list but not checking if an item is actually found? Maybe you are trying to use the contents of the `SelectedRegion` property and it is null as nothing is selected?

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
    }

    void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DataContext = new Data();

        cbOrganisation.IsEnabled = false;
        cbRegions.IsEnabled = false;

        cbOrganisation.SelectedIndex = 2;
        cbRegions.SelectedIndex = 3;
    }
}

public class Data
{
    public Data()
    {
        OrganisationEntries = new List<Organisation>();
        OrganisationEntries.AddRange(new[]  { 
                                                new Organisation(){  Description = "Acme Products"
                                                                    ,Regions=new List<Region>(){     new Region(){Code="NY", Description="New York"}
                                                                                                    ,new Region(){Code="FL", Description="Florida"}
                                                                                                }
                                                                   }
                                                ,new Organisation(){ Description = "Acme Investments"
                                                                    ,Regions=new List<Region>(){    new Region(){Code="NY",Description="New York"}
                                                                                                    ,new Region(){Code="TX", Description="Texas"}
                                                                                                }
                                                                    }
                                                ,new Organisation(){ Description = "Acme Inflatable Cows"
                                                                    ,Regions=new List<Region>(){     new Region(){Code="WY", Description="Wyoming"}
                                                                                                    ,new Region(){Code="WA",Description="Washington"}
                                                                                                    ,new Region(){Code="IO", Description="Iowa"}
                                                                                                    ,new Region(){Code="KY", Description="Kentucky"}
                                                                                                }
                                                                    }
                                            });
    }

    public List<Organisation> OrganisationEntries { get; set; }

    public Organisation SelectedOrganisation { get; set; }
    public int SelectedOrganisationIndex { get; set; }

    public Region SelectedRegion { get; set; }
    public int SelectedRegionIndex { get; set; }
}

public class Organisation
{
    public Organisation()
    {
        Regions = new List<Region>();
    }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<Region> Regions { get; set; }
}

public class Region
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ComboBox x:Name="cbOrganisation"
              Grid.Row="0"
              Grid.Column="1" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding OrganisationEntries}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedOrganisation, Mode=TwoWay}"
              SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedOrganisationIndex}"
              DisplayMemberPath="Description"
              Height="50"
              />

    <ComboBox x:Name="cbRegions"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="1" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=cbOrganisation, Path=SelectedItem.Regions}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRegion, Mode=TwoWay}"
                SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedRegionIndex}"
                DisplayMemberPath="Description" 
                Height="50"
              />


</Grid>
```